# Find a simplest proposition that is logically equivalent to ¬p ↔ ¬q (don't need a solution,need explanation).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I made a truth table, and found that the simplest proposition is

p <-> q

**My question is whether it is certain this is the simplest form, because nothing else could fit that truth table simpler than the biconditional right?**

**Also is ¬p ↔ ¬q the contrapositive of  p <-> q>**

I feel like this is really obvious, but I don't have enough knowledge to know if I'm being ignorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on what the question means by 'simplest', but in terms of number of symbols, you cannot do better: the truth of the statement clearly depends on $p$: if $p$ is true, then you get a different truth-value for the statement than when $p$ is false. Same goes for $q$. So, the statement needs both a $p$ and a $q$ ... and therefore also at elast one operator. So, your statement, that has a single $p$, a single $q$, and one operator is 'simplest' in terms of number of symbols.

An equally 'simple' statement would be $q \leftrightarrow p$ of course.

Finally, is $\neg p \leftrightarrow \neg q$ the contrapositive of $p \leftrightarrow q$?  Well, it's a little unusual to talk about contrapositives of biconditionals, as typically this is used for one-way conditionals: the contrapositive of $p \rightarrow q$ is $\neg q \rightarrow \neg p$.  But, as such, if there is such a thing as a contrapositive of a bi-conditional, I would expect it to be $\neg q \leftrightarrow \neg p$ ... although that is of course equivalent to $\neg p \leftrightarrow \neg q$.

Comment: Ha, that's funny: I searched for contrapositive of biconditional ... and found myself! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134093/contraposition-of-p-if-and-only-if-q/2134116#2134116